# mysql Select duplicate rows(based on a column) for each id (not unique)

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a table as below.

```
secId   sedol        mic
258     887754       XHKG
258     B0CRGS8      XPFT
258     B10RVH1      XNCD
258     B709630      XNCD
258     BK9YH34      XFRG
471     BF1SPP7      XHYF
471     BDCCPF4      XHYF
471     TK3YH32      XJTE
857     BG4YC54      XHEV
857     BS5YS63      XYEC
857     BK9YH64      XUTE
857     BU2YR21      XAVT
```

I want result as:

```
secId   sedol        mic
258     B10RVH1      XNCD
258     B709630      XNCD
471     BF1SPP7      XHYF
471     BDCCPF4      XHYF
```

For each unique secId I want to select rows where mic column value is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, analytic functions make this easy to do:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY secId, mic) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT secId, sedol, mic
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >= 2;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can try joining to a subquery which finds the counts for each `secId`/`mic` group:

```sql
SELECT t1.secId, t1.sedol, t1.mic
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT secId, mic
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY secId, mic
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) t2
    ON t2.secId = t1.secId AND
       t2.mic = t1.mic;
```

Comment: Well I find all things are easy if you just do it all for me

Comment: Incidentally, 'non-unique' doesn't require counts.

Answer (score 0):

Your table:

```
use test;

drop table if exists mytable;

create table mytable (secId int, sedol varchar(34), mic char(20));

insert into mytable values
(258,     '887754',       'XHKG'), 
(258,     'B0CRGS8',      'XPFT'),
(258,     'B10RVH1',      'XNCD'),
(258,     'B709630',      'XNCD'),
(258,     'BK9YH34',      'XFRG'),
(471,     'BF1SPP7',      'XHYF'),
(471,     'BDCCPF4',      'XHYF'),
(471,     'TK3YH32',      'XJTE'),
(857,     'BG4YC54',      'XHEV'),
(857,     'BS5YS63',      'XYEC'),
(857,     'BK9YH64',      'XUTE'),
(857,     'BU2YR21',      'XAVT');
```

Following query will do the job:

```
select
    a.secId,
    sedol,
    a.mic
from
    mytable a
join (
    select
        secId,
        mic,
        count(mic) miccount
    from
        mytable
    group by
        secId,
        mic
    having
        miccount > 1) b on
    a.secId = b.secId
    and a.mic = b.mic;
```